# Issue with running SSRS reports in Google Chrome

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-chrome, reporting-services

I have been building some new reports and hosting them in our SQL Server 2017 db and the current version of SSRS. However I am having an issue when running them from a laptop in Chrome in that they start to run and take a long time to complete. But if I run the same report in MS report builder from the same laptop it runs fine. It also runs fine in IE 11 and also in Chrome if I open it in an Incognito window. In case it is relevant the report has 3 parameters a Start and End date and a multi value parameter for the products we sell. Also the report uses a saved database account to connect to the datasource rather than needing to try and pass through the users network credentials.

If I open it on my Admin Terminal server it completely fine in Chrome without needing to do anything like use incognito mode. I even wondered if it was down to me being logged into a Google account in Chrome on my laptop but not being logged into one on the Terminal Server. But after logging into the same Google account on the terminal server the report still runs fine.

The authentication seems to be work fine as I can get onto the report portal without the need to manually enter my credentials and I can also navigate around the folders and reports and administer permissions and create subscriptions etc.

Comment: My users get this often. If I check the server activity, the query processing is normally finished but the browser just sits there "Loading". Just clearing the browser cache resolves it usually (Shift+Ctrl+Del).

Comment: Clearing the browser cache worked initially but after 2 runs of the report it slowed down again.